# cant parse axios errors

Tags: javascript, axios

I have the following in my typescript file

```
    async createProduct(data) {
        return await axios.post(request).catch(error => {
            console.log('error'.bgRed.white.bold, error)
        });
    }
```

that error looks like this when logged

[image]

I need to single out the error from the outside api which looks like this

[image]

#### How do I single out that part like any other object *ie* `return error.title`

## Update

here is the full response https://jsoneditoronline.org/#left=cloud.c584e42736664e9595fcfd8bb9c668a4

Comment: `error.data.title`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `const errorObject = JSON.parse(error.config.data)`.

If the syntax in the string is correct, you should be able to access the title as usual `errorObject.title`

Comment: I dont know how `JSON.parse(error.config.data)` works but `JSON.parse(error.config)` does not... i updated my answer can help me target the response data... This is an object but i dont understand why it is not behaving the same as other objects.

Comment: JSON.parse parses a string to JSON.
error.config.data is actually a string, that's why you couldn't access values inside of it like Category etc. 
Is that what was unclear?

Also, your JSON shows that there is a function toJSON delievered with the response. You shoud be able to access that with error.config.toJSON();